# How do I add `java` to the command path on Vista?

Tags: java, command-line, windows-vista, path, environment-variables

I have JDK installed in Vista. I want to run `java` from the command line. How do I configure the path variable?

If I'm not able to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable, what is an alternative?

Comment: hmm...just by upgrading to higher version of XP we have to go through this again :(

Comment: when you install java it puts a copy of java.exe into your windows directory, which is already in your path.  so, in general, you dont need to worry about it.

Comment: djangofan if you just install the RE you need to the add the path - at least i did - I see java.exe was put in SysWOW64 under Windows which is not in ones path by default

Answer (score 4):

Open My Conputer -> General Settings -> Environment variables and add as global

Key:JAVA_HOME
Value:C:\jsdk etc. etc.

And then modify the Path variable

Value ( type at the end )

```
 ....something;something;something;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Reopen your command prompt and type

```
 javac
```

And see if it works

**EDIT**

Moved my comment to the answer

The command prompt has some problems dealing with the empty space.

What I usually do is install the jdk directly on C: to get rid of space in "Program Files"

So installing it directly in C: will give you an "spaceless" path to the executable:

```
  C:\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\javac
```

Instead of

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\javac
```

Some times you'll get: C:\Program "executable not found" or something like that.

Installing directly on C: does the trick

Comment: I did the following configuration 
set JAVA_HOME=C:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_14
set Path=JAVA_HOME\bin;%PATH%
set classpath=.;
I am still unable to compile the java program.

Comment: Just to be clear, it should have been set Path=__%__JAVA_HOME__%__\bin;%PATH%

Comment: I did install the jdk in C drive, then it worked. The problem was with the space in "Program Files". Thanks.

Comment: You can handle empty spaces if you add quotes: path=....;something;something;"c:\program files\java....\bin"

Comment: forget about JAVA_HOME, just append to you system path the path to java.exe

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the java tutorial.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 0):

[CLASSPATH manual](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

[Running java from the command line](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the java program is available in your path then you should just be able to do;

```
c:> java -classpath somedir com.example.Main
```

if java isn't available to you then you can do

```
c:> SET JAVA_HOME=c:\path\to\java
c:> <same java stuff from above>
```

Comment: In general, JAVA_HOME doesn't do anything. Some shell scripts written to launch Java applications (like ant) recognize this environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`-classpath` option for the `java` command](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) to specify where your classes are.

The value of the classpath option is a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives that contain classes, structured into directories that mirror the classes' package structure. The list uses the path delimiter, which is plaform specific: on Windows, it is "`;`", other platforms use "`:`".

Using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is discouraged because changes for one program are likely to interfere with the operation of other programs.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with Vista and the path variable containing `%JAVA_PATH%` if the `JAVA_PATH` value has spaces.

I fixed this manually by setting the `%JAVA_PATH%` to `c:\program files\Java\<whatever>` and then added to `c:\program files\Java\<whatever>\bin` to the `Path` variable in Vista.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your My Computer icon, you can also go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings (which gives you System Properties dialog) -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables. Path is listed in the second text window.